# Is it possible to single out dependencies from one project in maven?

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to hack into an existing project (lets call it `bar`) to test my project (lets call it `foo`).

So in `bar`s pom, I added a dependency of `foo`. Right when I do this, all the existing tests in `bar` start failing, as in doesn't even start (these are some integration tests that make DB calls). I am certain that there is some dependency in `foo` that is driving `bar` mad. Is there some command or way that will show me only those dependencies that have been overridden after adding `foo` to `bar` as a dependency?

Comment: They are failing just because you are adding the dependency without changing the integration test code?

Comment: Yes. I did not touch the code. This is legacy code using java 1.4. And my new project is using java 7. But the funny thing is it fails without me even using the new dependency in code.

Comment: Than you have other problems if you not adding a dependency which might cause problems with transititive dependencies which can be checked by `mvn dependency:tree`...

Comment: Try `mvn dependency:analyze` to analyze the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

If you're using eclipse, go to the dependency hierarchy tab on your pom.xml.
Then with the dependencies that you don't want, use this construct:

```
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
```

Also, you can add `<scope>test</scope>` and it will not be added into your jar file (I think).

Comment: umm.. I am actually trying to figure out what exactly to exclude. I don't want to go through the pain of bruteforcing it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any built-in feature of Maven that will list *exactly* the changed dependencies. However, you can get a good overview of what changed by running

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

and

```
mvn dependency:analyze
```

on the project. Both will output a list of all dependencies (direct and transitive), in different formats. Run these once without, and once with your changes, then compare the results (make sure to reorder the results as required, because even unchanged dependencies may be listed in a different order). That should get you started in figuring out what changed.

---

Also, consider whether there is a problem independent of maven and dependencies. Maybe the project scans the classpath for dependency injection, and chokes on one of the new classes? Or maybe it does funny things with reflection. No idea if this is the problem, but just try to keep an open mind.